# How can I convert POI HSSFWorkbook to bytes?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Calling Simple [`toBytes()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes%28%29) does produce the bytes, but Excel throws Warning.

> Lost Document information

Googling around gave me this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200610.mbox/%3Cloom.20061017T235349-739@post.gmane.org%3E) and looking at [Javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes%28%29) for worksheet and POI [HOW-TO](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/how-to.html) say similar things. Basically, I cannot get `Bytes` without losing some information and should use the `write` method instead.

While write does work fine, I really need to send the bytes over. Is there any way I can do that? That is, get the bytes without getting any warning.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As that mailing list post said

> Invoking [`HSSFWorkbook.getBytes()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes%28%29) does not return all of the data necessary to re-
>   construct a complete Excel file.

You can use the write method with a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to get at the byte array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    workbook.write(bos);
} finally {
    bos.close();
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

(The `close` call is not really needed for a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but imho it is good style to include anyway in case its later changed to a different kind of stream.)

Comment: How can we do it in reverse way..? I mean Byte array to HSSFWorkbook?

Comment: @ChetanNellekeri It's probably better to ask that as a separate question

Comment: For anyone using C# this pretty much works there also, ByteArrayOutputStream is available in NPOI.utils

Answer (score 23):

How about:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(baos);
byte[] xls = baos.toByteArray();
```

In order to get a full excel file out, you must call the write(OutputStream) method. If you want bytes from that, just give a ByteArrayOutputStream