# apache POI - get size of generated excel file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for generating excel file in my spring mvc application. here is my spring action:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/excel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void companyExcelExport(@RequestParam String filter, @RequestParam String colNames, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    //code for generate excel file
    //....

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());

    response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + /* How can i access workbook size here*/);
}
```

I used `XSSFWorkbook` because i need to generate Excel 2007 format. but my problem is `XSSFWorkbook` does not have `getBytes` or `getSize` method. How can i calculate size of generated xlsx file?

EDIT: I used `ByteArrayOutputStream` like here:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); 
workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + byteArrayOutputStream.size());
```

Comment: Write the Workbook into a ByteArrayOutputStream, get the size from that, then write the bytes to the real stream?

Comment: I tried your solution, but still browser does not show file size.

Comment: please update the question , with how you used the ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: set the header **before** writing the response. And use [setContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29) to set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JB Nizet said : set the Header before writing the response .

so what you should do is the following :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + byteArrayOutputStream.size());
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

and please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187954/957654) , as it describes how to use the ByteArrayOutputStream  with the HSSFWorkbook .

Hope that helps .

Comment: Ok, this worked. thanks. But is there anyway to do that without ByteArrayOutputStream and with the XSSFWorkbook ?