# How to read data from excel using apache poi and store the data into String[][] array?

Tags: java, excel

I want to read data from excel using apache poi and store that data into 2Dimentional String Array. Using below code I will display data but I want to store the data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File f = new File("C:/Users/SYKAMREDDY/Desktop/testData.xls");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Data");
    int rc=sh.getLastRowNum()-sh.getFirstRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < rc; i++) {
        Row r = sh.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < r.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            String s = r.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you're facing? is the data being read successfully if yes what do you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use byteArray

simplified example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    workbook.write(bos);
} finally {
    bos.close();
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

also, take a look at [How can I convert POI HSSFWorkbook to bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186662/how-can-i-convert-poi-hssfworkbook-to-bytes)

if you want to use string , simpy do

```
String s = new String(bytes);
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question title, the questioner wants to store the cell data in a `string[][]` array. You are proposing to save the workbook in a `byte[]` array. So this is not an answer to the question.